# setState (In react functional component) is not updating the existing state in react todo app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have to do app using react and material ui which is combined of these components:

1- App.js

`

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header'
import ToDoApp from './components/ToDoApp';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <ToDoApp />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`

2- ToDoApp.js

`

```
import React from 'react'
import ToDoList from './ToDoList';
import Task from './Task';
import { Container, Grid } from '@mui/material';
import {useState, } from 'react';


export default function ToDoApp() {
        const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
        {   
            id: 1,
            Title: "Task 1",
            done: true
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            Title: "Task 2",
            done: true
        },
    ])  


    const deleteTask = (id) => {
        // console.log(id);
        const newtodos = todos.filter(function(todo) {
            return todo.id !== id;
        })

        setTodos(newtodos);
    }

    const addTodo = (todoTitle) => {
        const lastTodo = todos[todos.length-1];
        const newtodosId = lastTodo.id + 1;
        const newtodos = todos;
        newtodos.push({
            id: newtodosId,
            title: todoTitle,
            done: false,
        })
        setTodos(newtodos);
        
        console.log(newtodos);
    }


  return (
    <Container maxWidth="sm">
      <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
        <ToDoList newTodo={addTodo}/>
          
        <Task ToDoAppList={todos} DeleteTodoTask={deleteTask}/>

      </Grid>
      </Container>
  )
}
```

`
3- ToDoList.js

`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import { Add, AddToDriveOutlined } from '@mui/icons-material/';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

    
export default function ToDoList(props) {


const addTodo = props.newTodo
const [todo, setTodo] = useState('')
function writeTodo(e) {
  // console.log(e.target.value);
  setTodo(e.target.value);
}

  const addText = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addTodo(todo);
    // console.log(todo);
  }



  return (
          <>
            <Typography sx={{ mt: 4, mb: 2 }} variant="h6" component="div">
              ToDo List
            </Typography>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => addText(e)}>
            <FormControl>
            <div
            
            style={{display: 'flex', marginBottom: 20}}>
            <TextField
              id="standard-helperText"
              label="New ToDo"
              style={{ width: 450 }}
              variant="standard"
              value={todo}
              onChange={(e) => writeTodo(e)}
            />

            <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="create" type="submit">
              <Add />
            </IconButton>
            </div>
            </FormControl>
            </form>

            
          </>

  )
}
```

`

4-Task.js

`

```
import React from 'react'
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import { Tag, Check, Delete } from '@mui/icons-material';

export default function Task(props) {
    const tasks = props.ToDoAppList;
    const deleteTask = props.DeleteTodoTask;
    

    const List = tasks.map(task =>  { return(
        <Paper elevation={3} style={{padding: 10, marginTop: 10}} key={task.id}>
        <IconButton aria-label="create">
            <Tag />
        </IconButton>
        <span style={{textDecoration: 'line-through'}}>{task.Title}</span>
        <IconButton aria-label="delete" style={{float: 'right', color: 'red'}} onClick={()=>deleteTask(task.id)}>
            <Delete />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton aria-label="check" style={{float: 'right'}}>
            <Check />
        </IconButton>
              
    </Paper>
    )})
    
  return (
    <>
    {List}
    </>
  )
}
```

`

When Submitting the new Todo, the result is not shown on the DOM.

In the ToDoApp.js -> function "addTodo" I used setState to push the new array with the new item, and is sent to ToDoList.js -> form "onSubmit" event in "addText" function. I put the console.log in the function and I am getting the new array but it's not showing on the page.
The tasks listing is handled in the task.js by sending the array through props and using map function to loop over the array.
Note: I handled the delete function in the ToDoApp.js and it's woking with no problem. I don't understand why it's not running with "addTodo" funciton.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change title to Title (based on your state Schema)
then you dont need to update whole state just add your new task to your current state (function in setTodos)

```
 const addTodo = (todoTitle) => {
    const lastTodo = todos[todos.length - 1];
    const newtodosId = lastTodo.id + 1;
    let newTodo = {
      id: newtodosId,
      Title: todoTitle,
      done: false
    };
      setTodos((prev)=>[...prev,newTodo])
  };
```